# Storing/Updating an unpredictable list efficiently in a database

Tags: c#, t-sql, database-design

I have a list that contains each of the items in the order with a qty. Obviously the list will vary in size each time the order is updated. I would be interested in what would be most efficient when updating: a merge statement, or deleting all the items for that order and then adding all the items the customer selected.

I felt the merge statement was best as I wouldn't need to delete and add items that didn't change. The problem is that when adding items to the database, I will need to pass back the auto generated ID so I can keep track of it in the project. With a really slow server I wasn't sure that that was the most efficient. Especially as I need to pass the entire item back so I know which ID matches up with which object. Currently, I'm doing everything through a data-table in C# instead of running each item in a separate SQL query, so I get a list of the added items back from my merge statement with their IDs.

EDIT-
I'm afraid I haven't really clarified my question. I believe I understand the Merge statement. I am using the output from the Merge to pass back items with their auto-generated IDs. I am not asking how to do a merge. The question is why a merge is more efficient then deleting all the OrderItems for an Order and then adding the Items the user has selected back in. I need to pass in all the OrderItems for the Order when using a Merge so that the Merge doesn't delete the OrderItem anyway. What is the correct way of handling this scenario?

```cs
//Order.cs
public int OrderID {get; set;}
public List<OrderItem> {get; set;}
```

```
//OrderItem.cs
public int ItemID {get; set;} //Reference to Item.cs I'd add another ID to use merge?
public int Qty {get; set;}
```

```
//Item.cs
public int ItemID {get; set;}
public string DisplayName {get; set;}
public decimal ItemCost {get; set;}
```

```sql
--Orders.sql
OrderID int primary key identity
```

```sql
--OrderItems.sql
ID int primary key identity, 
OrderID int not null,
ItemID int not null,
Qty int not null,
constraint [FK_OrderItems_Orders] foreign key ([OrderID]) references [Orders]([OrderID]),
constraint [FK_OrderItems_Items] foreign key ([ItemID]) references [Items]([ItemID])
```

```sql
--Items.sql
ItemID int primary key identity,
DisplayName varchar(100) not null,
ItemCost money not null
```

Comment: When you add something, the auto generated id is just the max id of the table if you are using an identity column. I'd say go with that unless you are going to be doing this extremely frequently.

Comment: @Democrats updates would not be frequent. You're saying doing a merge and keeping track of the IDs would be better?

Comment: If you were to keep things in a relational database, you'd create an orders table and an items table, with a foreign key relationship between the two.  If you were to use Entity Framework and a typical integer (r long)ID column in each database, EF would model the foreign key relationship by having each order containing a collection of items.  When you make an update, EF would magically make everything work (for some definition of magic)

Comment: @Flydog57 Ah yes. I am doing the relational database/foreign key setup, just not EF. I was hoping to avoid unleashing the beast into my delicate project. If its unavoidable I guess it will just have to happen.

Comment: In this design, what happens to historical Orders when an Item's price is changed? You need price in OrderItems.

Comment: @HardCode good point. I do in the real code, just not here to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Merge syntax allows `output` clause, which you can use to output auto-generated ids: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear. Check the edit. I am not asking how to do a merge.

Comment: Ah, ok. It seems you are asking why merge is more efficient. This is because it doesn't touch records that don't need to be touched. Also, if performance is your concern, don't use C# DataTable, use SqlDataReader directly. In a number of scenarios I tested, there was 2x to 5x difference.